# how to use a div to catch falling divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so far I've generated some random divs at the top of the page and want to make them fall down the page. The main purpose is as they fall down, I want the right hand side blue div "catch" the falling divs (it moves to "catch" as we resize window). So whenever the blue div touches/collide with? any of the falling divs, the falling div sticks onto the blue div at the exact position where they touched and stops falling down—— caught divs now move with the blue div. and this builds up as it "catches" more.

I really don't have a lot of knowledge of javascript and as I was sort of playing around I'm wondering if this is even possible with javascript? Is there a way to detect the divs touching?

I've attached a codepen:
https://codepen.io/cocotx/pen/vYmeBpr

```
window.addEventListener('load', init);

function init() {
  let shapes = [];
  let add = 0.1;

  var w = document.getElementById('falling-point').offsetWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;

  function randomInRange(from, to) {
      let x = Math.random() * (to - from);
      return x + from;
  };

  function createShape() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'shapes');
    div.style.left = randomInRange(0, w)+'px';
    div.style.top = 0+'px';
    const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    div.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
    div.style.width = randomInRange(10, 90)+'px';
    div.style.height = randomInRange(20, 80)+'px';
    div.style.borderRadius = randomInRange(0, 50)+'px';
    div.style.borderRadius = randomInRange(0, 50)+'px';
    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(div);
    shapes.push(div);
  }

  function mainLoop() {
    let x = Math.random();
    if (x < 0.01) {
      createShape();
    }
    shapes.forEach(e => e.style.top -= add);
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
  }
  mainLoop();

};
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the solution have to use divs?  This might be better suited to a canvas or the likes--something that's more suited for drawing shapes and whatnot.

Comment: First thing to fix: `e.style.top -= add`, the top style is a string e.g. `10px` so `-=` isn't going to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula for detecting collision between rectangles:

```
if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
   rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
   rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
   rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y) {
    // collision detected!
}
```

(From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection)